# Defering FILE flush to when the file is closed

Tags: c

I want to defer flushing the contents of the **FILE*** to when **fclose** is called. In other words, I only want to write to disk when **fclose** is called and keep buffering the contents until then. Is it possible to do that with **FILE*** or I need to write my own code?

Comment: Why don't you wait to call fclose until you are finished? I don't understand.

Comment: I think, contents are flushed even before fclose. I've read that when you have something like this fprintf( file, "something!\n" ); the contents will be flushed, due to the new line character. In other words, fprintf, flushes the contents of the buffer on seeing the newline character.

Comment: @MetallicPriest I don't think newline *always* causes a flush to happen. Functions like printf buffer output to a memory buffer created per file handle (which is why they're not threadsafe) and if this buffer fills up over some threshold the contents get flushed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to buffer (and under no circumstances write to the disk until the file is closed), then your best bet is to write to a buffer in memory (assuming that it will *fit* in memory, of course), and then write that buffer in one go and then call `fclose()`.